# Scheduling Multiple Non Recurring Non Fixed Interval Events

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hi I am trying to create a simple program to schedule an event to be triggered after some time whenever a button is clicked.

For my code below i can getting all the received event together at once instead of at the tabulated interval.

The code are as follows :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.the_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void setup() {
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("mm:ss ", d.getTime());
            Log.i("trigger"," " + s);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.text.timer") );
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.text.timer"), 0 );
    am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setup();
    am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + TWENTY_SECONDS, pi );
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("mm:ss ", d.getTime());
    Log.i("clicked"," " + s);
    count++;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    am.cancel(pi);
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My Logcat testing result

```
06-29 05:04:05.501: I/clicked(1849):  04:05 
06-29 05:04:06.561: I/clicked(1849):  04:06 
06-29 05:04:07.551: I/clicked(1849):  04:07 
06-29 05:04:09.621: I/trigger(1849):  04:09 
06-29 05:04:09.651: I/trigger(1849):  04:09 
06-29 05:04:09.701: I/trigger(1849):  04:09 
06-29 05:04:09.741: I/trigger(1849):  04:09 
06-29 05:04:09.781: I/trigger(1849):  04:09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

-don't register a receiver every click. do it once (in you onCreate for instance).

-in order for you to get different onReceive calls on the same broadcast, you need to add a request code to each one of your pending intents. you can use "count" for that.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s = DateFormat.format("mm:ss ", d.getTime());
            Log.i("trigger", " " + s);
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.text.timer"));

    findViewById(R.id.the_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, count, new Intent(
            "com.text.timer"), 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + TWENTY_SECONDS, pi);
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence s = DateFormat.format("mm:ss ", d.getTime());
    Log.i("clicked", " " + s);
    count++;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    am.cancel(pi);
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried your code . However the result is still the same all as before . All the received is triggered at once instead of at the interval which i pressed the button.

Comment: Did you use exactly my code? because this works perfectly fine on my device (I ran it and it works as it should)

Comment: Hi , i works fine now after i clean the project. However is there a way i can get the request code or i have to access it through a intent.putExtra ?

Comment: Add an extra... its simple enough. And if this helped you, please mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651) is a good tut...not sure of the question, though. I found the link useful, however.